# How to change the default font and paper size in word using word.js

Tags: javascript, ms-office

I am trying to add insert template using word.js api but it always take word default font and paper size ??
Is there any way I can override the defaults???
my code is

```
    Word.run(function (ctx) {

        var body = ctx.document.body;
        body.clear();
        body.insertFileFromBase64(base64, "replace");


        return ctx.sync()
        .then(function () {
            handleSuccess();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            handleError(error);
        })
    });
```

but the final result is not the same as the original document such as 
base64 document has font "Times New Roman" in the new document I am getting different font
also the page size in the original document is A4 but the page size in the new document is paper

Comment: Your question is not clear at all, you need to add much more details, code snippets, expected results and elaborate the problem you are facing if you want us to help you.

Comment: I tried to add more details, please let me know now

Comment: Is wordjs a dead project?  The github page is a 404.

Comment: And what is this word.js ? Is it a module you created or something you are using ?

Comment: by word.js I mean office api 'javascript' to create add ins

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
var body = ctx.document.body;
body.clear();
body.font.name = 'Arial';
body.insertFileFromBase64(base64, "replace");
```

I am not sure what you mean by paper size but you can look through the [documentation](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body) for how to set the size.

Comment: Thank you for your reply what i mean by paper size is word page size
also another question if the my font is already included in the base64 why it cant be applied directly ?

Comment: It's clearly not being applied to the body so either it is not set correctly in your file or **body** is not able to load it, in which case you can fetch the font from your file and apply directly to **body** using the code above.